# Optimizing using Cython for Python Objects with hidden class implementation

Tags: python, c, cython, cythonize

Let's say I have a class as below:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,python_object):
        self.my_python_object = python_object
        
    def my_function(self):
        for item in self.my_python_object.getItems():
            item.do_something()
```

In the above class, the implementation/class of the initial "python_object" instance is unknown, and I get this object via an API. Most of my code revolves around calling methods from this API's object. The cython implementation I have created is like below,

```
cdef class A():
    cdef public object my_python_object
    def __init__(self,python_object):
        self.my_python_object = python_object
        
    cdef void my_function(self):
        cdef object item
        for item in self.my_python_object.getItems():
            item.do_something()
```

Since it is not a primitive type, the cython/c optimization does not work as it should(I think because defining a variable as an "object" type is the same as not defining it at all in the context of performance improvement) and a lot of Python/C API calls are made reducing the overall performance of the program.

Is there a way to let cython know or define some sort of dummy structure which specifies that the "python_object" has only said functions which return said type of values without actually knowing the original class structure of "python_object". I am thinking by doing this, cython can reduce the Python/C API calls.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that an object will have any items.  The python object could hold a pointer to a c like struct/c++ class and it gets the items from that?

Comment: @TomMcLean I am slightly confused. "You cannot guarantee that an object will have any items." --> Can I not force it someway by making sure I pass the exact objects which I know contain known methods and attributes types(but not the exact implementation).
"The python object could hold a pointer to a c like struct/c++ class and it gets the items from that?" --> This unfortunately cant be done. I don't even have the implementation location anywhere.. Or do you mean I should convert the objects to pointers ?

Comment: python objects are not strictly typed, if you wanted to you can force an object to have any attributes you want, or none at all. You can "enforce" it within your code, but you cant enforce it at the machine level

Comment: Unless you're prepared to force `my_python_object` to be an inherited from some Cython abstract base class, then probably not.